# Windows 2012 RTM Dell G1 1950 and MD3000 with a SAS5 controller?

Tags: windows, dell, sas, windows-server-2012

Seems like a June 6th post by Dell states that the RTM version of Windows Server 2012 should have all the necessary drivers for a <kbd>Dell G1 1950</kbd> -> <kbd>SAS5</kbd> -> <kbd>md3000</kbd> setup.

Can anybody who's tried this verify if it works or not?

(And yes I'd love to upgrade this stuff but I don't think there's a budget for that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as it most likely will not be supported by Dell after GA as the 1950s are nearing end-of-life the official response would be no it might not work.  However, you won't know until you try it.

Comment: yep kinda what I've been thinking, was just hoping that somebody may have tried this combo already.

Comment: Yea its still a bit early for a lot of testing to have been done or published really regarding 2012.  My general sense is that if 2008R2 works out of the box 2012 is probably going to be ok. You may just need to get the proper MD3000 install package and drivers from Dell though.

Answer (score 2):

It works but isn't stable or supported at least in clustered mode. 
My config is a little different (2 R710 with SAS5 and MD3000)

Loaded the support from the latest ISO and it looked correct but gave disk errors when I started pushing it with SQLIO.

Support stated the SAS5, MPIO, & MD3000 drivers weren't available. 
When I asked for an ETA he wouldn't commit to one even in beta.